# command like wc but with tee behaviour

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, pipe, tee, wc

I want to backup a database using `psql` and `COPY` command. here is my script:

```
psql "user=${USERNAME} host=${HOSTNAME} dbname=${DBNAME} password=${PASSWORD}" -c \
"COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) ORDER BY id ASC) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;" | \
bzip2 -z -f --best -c > /home/${DBNAME}-${FILENAME}.csv.bz2
```

Also I want to know how many lines are copied from database but psql does not have such feature. so I need external command. I need something like this:

```
psql ... | wc -l | bzip2
```

Is there any solution? The only solution I have found is to use fifo:

```
mkfifo /home/backup.fifo
psql ... | tee /home/backup.fifo | bzip2
```

Now from another terminal window I can use `wc`:

```
wc -l /home/backup.fifo
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `bash` and `zsh` have a `>(pipeline)` feature:

```
psql ... | tee >(wc -l) | bzip2
```

Note that the `>` here is not a normal redirection, but a necessary part of the syntax.  You would need a second `>` if you wanted to combine it with an actual redirection (with a space in between so it wouldn't be read as `>>` redirect-for-append).

Comment: what is `>(wc -l)` called so I can search it? :D

Comment: @MajidAzimi It's called [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

Comment: You probably want `>(wc -l >&2)` unless you want the `wc` output to get bzipped as well.

Comment: That is an... interesting... `bash` behavior; I would expect it to be independent of the rest of the pipeline (and in `zsh` it is).